# Get XPATH of certain element in python (without using 'lxml')

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree, apache-nifi

I Have an XML (Output.xml):

```
<condition>
    <comparison compare="and">
        <comparison compare="contains">
            <operand  type="string"/>
            <operand type="string" value="Agent"/>
        </comparison>
        <comparison compare="gt">
            <operand type="float"/>
            <operand type="int" />
        </comparison>
    </comparison>
</condition>
```

The python code which works perfectly:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('Output.xml')

for condition in tree.xpath('//operand'):   
    print tree.getelementpath(condition)
```

Result:

```
/condition/comparison/comparison[1]/operand[1]
/condition/comparison/comparison[1]/operand[2]
/condition/comparison/comparison[2]/operand[1]
/condition/comparison/comparison[2]/operand[2]
```

I am using Apache NiFi(use Jython) which do not  support the 'LXML' module. Is there any way I can get the same output with a different module like xml.etree.ElementTree where I can extract the xpath of certain elements from the provided xml?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xml.etree.ElementTree`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('output.xml').getroot()

root = e.tag
print(root)
for c in e.findall('.//'):
    print(c.tag)
```

Just showing you how to proceed, (this gives you all the tags in the xml)

```
condition
comparison
comparison
operand
operand
comparison
operand
operand
```